# Replace in TSql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update a row which is in format like this `ABC - DEF - GHI - ABD`,
Using a cmd like this `UPDATE tbl SET col = Replace(col,@var, '') WHERE Pk=something.`  How can I remove the trailing or leading hyphens? For exmaple if @var is GHI, after replace, row value should be ABC-DEF-ABD or if @var is ABC then value should be DEF - GHI - ABD.

Comment: Making an assumption here but don't store delimited lists in the database. Instead use a one to many junction table then this is a simple `delete` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not my call. We do have a one to many relation table this col is just used for display purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, agree completely with comment above.. Change teh data sschema to not store delimited lists of values in database column.

But, if this is not possible, Try this:

```
Update Table Set 
   colName = Replace(Replace(colName, '- ' + @var, ''), @var + ' -', '')
Where pk = @pk
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra ' - ' to the end of the string, replace @var with the dash appended, then strip the trailing ' - ' when you're done.

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET col = LEFT(REPLACE(col + ' - ', @var+' - ', ''), LEN(col)-6)
    WHERE Pk = something
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = replace(replace(col, @var + ' – ', ''), ' – ' + @var, '')
```

The inner replace replaces all middle and “leading” instances, and the outer replace catches any “final” instances.

If there are single instances, e.g. `GHI`, add a further and outermost call:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = replace(replace(replace(col, @var + ' – ', ''), ' – ' + @var, ''), @var, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
-- 1: replace(col,@var, '') => your replacement
-- 2: replace(#1, ' - ', '-') => remove spaces
-- 3: replace(#2, '- ', '') => remove first hyphen and space
-- 4: replace(#3, ' -', '') => remove last hyphen and space

UPDATE tbl
   SET col = replace(replace(replace(replace(col,@var, ''), ' - ', '-'), '- ', ''), ' -', '')        
 WHERE Pk=something
```